# Randomize dataframe in r

Tags: r, random, permutation

A dataframe which is randomized and sorted using `Object` column is shown below as an example. The `order` is applied to `sample` only to organize similar objects together. Will it be possible to avoid the `order` operation and achieve randomization within the repeating `Object` column? Thanks.

```
set.seed(7)
# read csv
df <- read.csv("~/Documents/test.csv", header = T)
df
     Object Tag Comment
1         1   A      C1
2         1   B      C2
3         1   C      C3
4         1   D      C4
5         2   A      A1
6         2   C      A2
7         2   F      A3
8         2   G      A4
9         3   P      C1
10        3   N      A1
11        3   P      B5
# randomize the order of the df
dfr <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
dfr
    Object Tag Comment
11      3   P      B5
4       1   D      C4
2       1   B      C2
1       1   A      C1
9       3   P      C1
5       2   A      A1
7       2   F      A3
10      3   N      A1
8       2   G      A4
3       1   C      C3
6       2   C      A2 
#sort dfr using Object field
dfrSort <- dfr[with(dfr, order(Object)), ]
dfrSort
     Object Tag Comment
4         1   D      C4
2         1   B      C2
1         1   A      C1
3         1   C      C3
5         2   A      A1
7         2   F      A3
8         2   G      A4
6         2   C      A2
11        3   P      B5
9         3   P      C1
10        3   N      A1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'Object' do the `sample`ing to not break the ties

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Object) %>% 
     slice(sample(row_number()))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   Object [3]
#   Object   Tag Comment
#    <int> <chr>   <chr>
# 1      1     C      C3
# 2      1     B      C2
# 3      1     A      C1
# 4      1     D      C4
# 5      2     C      A2
# 6      2     F      A3
# 7      2     G      A4
# 8      2     A      A1
# 9      3     P      B5
#10      3     P      C1
#11      3     N      A1
```

Comment: Thanks but the last two columns should randomize together (in pairs)  as shown in the example. For `Object 1 Tag D` should always be paired with `Comment C4`, and so forth when shuffled.  The same is the case for the other `Object`s.

Comment: I believe it is. Pasting from my question "The order is applied to `sample` only to organize similar objects together. Will it be possible to avoid the `order` operation and achieve randomization within the repeating Object column? "

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of giving an example with sample output required?

Comment: @deepseefan okay, now check it.  I thought you wanted to break the order of columns